# PostgreSQL `HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.` on update of a column with type POINT

Tags: database, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 with PostGIS 2.0.1.

The type of column `location` is `point`. type of `latitude` and `longitude` double precision.

Why is this update statement

```
update list_of_location SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude), 4326);
```

returning

```
LINE 1: update list_of_location SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longit...
                                               ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use PostGIS 2.0+, `location` should be of type `geometry(Point,4326)`, and *not* [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6432).